# Validate date against set of rules

Tags: c#, sql, validation, date

I'm writing an application that needs to limit what time orders are placed based on a set of rules. I've got two questions, what's the best way to store the rules in a MSSQL table, and what's the best way to validate a Date against them?

eg.

- Orders cannot be placed on any Saturday between 1200 and 1700.
- Orders cannot be placed on any Christmas day (25/12) between 0000 and 2359
- Orders cannot be placed on 10/3/2013 between 1500 and 1600.

My original plan would be to have a table would have 4 columns, (start time, end time, single rule/recurring rule).

But, i'm not sure how to take into account the Day of week vs Date in year vs Absolute date.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can check `DayofWeek()` in .Net have you explored that option? you could create a `public Enum DayOfWeek { Monday, Tuesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday }` and check or do a switch against that and within that do some additional logic just an idea

Comment: what you need is some simple set of logic! `SO WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED`?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at an open source scheduling effort like http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/  See how they model and store their schedules for ideas that should map pretty closely to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was to have 3 tables (Day of year, Day of week and Absolute Date) which override DateConstraint which contains start/end times for each rule.

[image: entity framework diagram for time matching]

The validation code was relatively simple. I added the Matches() routine to all classes.

```
public partial class DateConstraint
{
    public virtual bool Matches()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks >= StartTime.Ticks && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks <= EndTime.Ticks;
    }
}

public partial class DayOfWeekConstraint : DateConstraint
{
    public override bool Matches()
    {
        return base.Matches() && this.DayOfWeek == Convert.ToInt16(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
    }
}

public partial class DayOfYearConstraint : DateConstraint
{
    public override bool Matches()
    {
        return base.Matches() && Date.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month;
    }
}

public partial class AbsoluteDateConstraint : DateConstraint
{
    public override bool Matches()
    {

        return base.Matches() && Date.Day == DateTime.Now.Day && Date.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year;
    }
}
```

To do the validation I simply do

```
foreach(var dateConstraint in Restaurant.DateConstraints)
{
   if(!dateConstraint.Matches()) { return false; }
}
```